# Bigquery Fail fast and rollback

Tags: google-bigquery, rollback

We are trying to insert records into bigquery via insertAll.... As per my understanding the method insertAll tries to insert the records and returns response only after the job is complete. The issue is we would like to configure the fail fast behavior, like a handler or listener which can send the notification as soon as failure has taken place, and rollback of data in case of failure to insert. currently bq is trying to insert all the records. below is detailed code

```
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
        log.info("New success!!! Time required to acquire big query connection: "
                + TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert((System.nanoTime() - startTime), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));

        TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, table);
        long bigQueryInsertStartTime = System.nanoTime();

        log.info("Big Query insert begin " + bigQueryInsertStartTime);

        InsertAllResponse response = bigquery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest.of(tableId, data));

        if (response.hasErrors()) {

            response.getInsertErrors().entrySet().forEach(x -> log.error(x.getValue().toString()));
            log.error("insertion into table Single row" + table + "failed");

        } else {
            log.debug("inserted into table Single row: " + table + " successfully");
        }
```